# Emacs: display using hexadecimal escape sequences

Tags: emacs

Emacs displays characters without glyphs as octal escape sequences "\OOO", e.g., from the start of a PDF file:

```
%PDF-1.4
%\344\343\317\322
1 0 obj
[/PDF/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI/Text]
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Length 5 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>
stream
9\323\317\221\321\356j\305
endstream
```

Can I set some (relatively simple) configuration to get those in hexadecimal escape sequences "\xFF"? As:

```
%PDF-1.4
%\xE4\xE3\xCF\xD2
1 0 obj
[/PDF/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI/Text]
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Length 5 0 R/Filter/FlateDecode>>
stream
9\xD3\xCF\x91\xD1\xEEj\xC5
endstream
```

(using text-mode, or fundamental-mode, or... but not hexl-mode)

Answer (score 2):

I've never played with this before, but reading the Elisp manual a bit and experimenting makes me think that something like this is what you're looking for:

```
(let ((ii          128)
      (new-dtable  (make-display-table))
      (hex-string  nil))
  (while (< ii 256) ; Convert decimal codes 128 to 255.
    (setq hex-string  (format "%X" ii))
    (aset new-dtable ii
          (vector
           (make-glyph-code ?\ 'escape-glyph)
           (make-glyph-code ?x 'escape-glyph)
           (make-glyph-code (aref hex-string 0) 'escape-glyph)
           (make-glyph-code (aref hex-string 1) 'escape-glyph)))
    (setq ii  (1+ ii)))
  (set-window-display-table (selected-window) new-dtable))
```

If you then use, say `C-q 3 4 4 RET`, which normally inserts the octal escape sequence `\344`, it will insert a glyph showing `xE4`.

The relevant part of the Elisp manual I looked at are those under node `Character Display`.

Comment: Looks good, yet it does not work completely. I have no time now to investigate deeper, but it seems it is converting newly inserted characters, but not the pre-existant ones

Comment: That sounds it has to do with the way the redisplay and the display table work. I'm no expert on that. You might need to force redisplay (e.g. `force-mode-line-update` with `ALL` arg) or even revisit the buffer (e.g. `C-x v` or revert). (You are welcome to upvote or accept the answer, BTW. ;-) )

Comment: Upvoted because it is useful, not accepted (yet?) because it does not (yet) solve it. And I *hate* being asked to vote

Comment: FYI - For me it *does* also convert pre-existing chars in the buffer.  Did you try adding a call to `force-mode-line-update` (with non-nil arg)?  For me the code works with both Emacs 24 (recent dev snapshot) and Emacs 23.4, on MS Windows.

Comment: Try also iconifying (minimizing) and then restoring the frame, or just resizing the frame. Try also killing the buffer and re-creating it (at least to see whether that helps).